# I am new to callbacks and would like to know how the function below works

Tags: javascript, callback

```
function tempUpdates()
{
    getData(callbackID, "cabinetTemp", function(callback){  
       var currentTemp = convertBinary(callback);  
       for(var i = 0; i < tempUpdateList.length: i++)  
       {  
          tempUpdateList[i].innerHTML = currentTemp;  
       }  
   })  
}
```

I will not go into what each of the functions are but, I would like to know...

- When is the callback is actually executed? Is it after the loop has completed? (That is what I suspect.)
- Is the `currentTemp` variable loaded only after the loop completes?

Comment: Whatever happened to people reading or researching: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Comment: The [sample](http://sscce.org/) isn't complete. Without knowing how `getData` and `convertBinary` do what they do, there's no way to answer your first question of "when" without guessing.

Comment: It is impossible to know with what you've shown us.

Comment: is getData a library function you are using? which library?

Comment: How could the callback be executed *after* the loop has completed, when the loop is *inside* the callback?

Comment: ...or are you talking about whatever is being passed to the `callback` parameter (assuming that's a function)?

Answer (score 1):

A callback gets called whenever the initial function finishes its work and decides to call it. In your example it has nothing to do with the for-loop. That's entirely part of the callback. It's inside the callback, so it runs whenever the callback function runs, and not vice-versa.

It seems that getData is an AJAX function. So what it does is basically fetch the data from the server, and call the callback when it's done. The getData method itself is generic. All it does is what it says on the tin - get some data. What the programmer decides to do with the data is none of its concern. It just waits until the server sends the data back, and when it's ready, it calls the callback so that IT (a.k.a. the function that you, the programmer added there) does the application-specific stuff with the data received.

So imagine the getData function acting like this:

1. gets called, receives its parameters
2. ok, mr. callback, just stay put over there, key?
3. DUDE!, SERVER!, DUDE! GIMME DATA!
4. *a little bit of latency*
5. AH, HERE YA GO -
6. getData receives the data - "OK, I'm done here - YO, callback, take this data and do whatever you want with it, I'm through with my work"
7. callback processes the data

It doesn't just have to be AJAX, or JavaScript. In theory, a function that receives a callback as a parameter, pretty much just *calls that function back* as soon as it finishes its job. Usually it's some sort of action that's supposed to take place *after* the first functions (getData in our case) finishes its job (like getData gets the data).

Comment: +1 for `DUDE!, SERVER!, DUDE! GIMME DATA!` and `ok, mr. callback, just stay put over there, key?`!

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTemp = convertBinary(callback)
```

The callback is being sent to `convertBinary`.  It's ran depending on what that function does.  Unless `convertBinary` uses a timeout (or runs another asynchronous function such as AJAX), the callback would be ran before the loop starts.

`currentTemp` is "loaded" when `convertBinary` returns a value, which happens before the loop starts.  The loop seems to set various HTML elements to the value of `currentTemp`.

Obviously, none of this will run until `getData` calls the function (and passes it a callback).

Comment: or unless it does anything asynchronous, XHR, web workers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without any context. If you're really curious when the callback is executed you should try debugging the code. You can either add some logging so you can see the order of execution or, even better, set a breakpoint in the anonymous function you pass to getData and see what the stack looks like there).

The easiest way to get some insight would be some simple console.log("some meaningful string describing the current state"); calls, but debugging is a much more powerful technique. If you're using a webkit browser (chrome, safari), it's built in. Firefox has the wonderful firebug plugin that will let you debug javascript. I'm not sure of the current state of the art in debugging node.js, but there probably is a module you could use there.